# Can't stop page from refreshing on form submit react

Tags: reactjs, forms, express, axios, mern

I'm using axios to send a post request to my backend but I don't want it to refresh after submit. The problem is I can't seem to stop it and e.preventDefault() is not working to stop it.

My code for the react form is below,

```
    const labels = {
  0.5: 'Useless',
  1: 'Useless+',
  1.5: 'Poor',
  2: 'Poor+',
  2.5: 'Ok',
  3: 'Ok+',
  3.5: 'Good',
  4: 'Good+',
  4.5: 'Excellent',
  5: 'Excellent+',
};

function getLabelText(value) {
  return `${value} Star${value !== 1 ? 's' : ''}, ${labels[value]}`;
}



function ReviewCreateForm() {
  const { countryId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(2);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(-1);

  const user = JSON.parse(ReactSession.get('userId'));

  const [revValues, setrevValues] = useState({
    title: "",
    body: "",
    rating: 1,
    user: user.user.username
  });

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   CreateReview();
  // }, []);

  

  async function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
    
    
    await ReviewsService.create(countryId, revValues)
    .catch((error) => {
      if(error.response){
        console.log(error.response.data);
      }
    })
  
   
    navigate(`/country/${countryId}`, {
      state: { type: 'success', message: 'Review has been created.' },
    });
    navigate(0);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    
    }

  };

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <div className="my-2">
        <p className="italic">
          <Link to="/login" className="text-indigo-600 hover:underline">
            Sign in
          </Link>{" "}
          to leave a review!
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Paper elevation={6} sx={{ paddingX: 4, paddingY: 3 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ rowGap: 2 }} size="medium">
        <TextField
          label="title"
          onChange={(e) =>
            setrevValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, title: e.target.value }))
          }
        />
        {/* <Rating
          name="simple-controlled"
          value={revValues.rating}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setrevValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, rating: newValue }));
          }}
        /> */}
        <Box
      sx={{
        width: 200,
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Rating
        name="hover-feedback"
        value={revValues.rating}
        precision={0.5}
        getLabelText={getLabelText}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setrevValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, rating: newValue }))// setValue(newValue);
        }}
        onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
          setHover(newHover);
        }}
        emptyIcon={<StarIcon style={{ opacity: 0.55 }} fontSize="inherit" />}
      />
      {value !== null && (
        <Box sx={{ ml: 2 }}>{labels[hover !== -1 ? hover : value]}</Box>
      )}
    </Box>
        <TextField
          label="body"
          multiline
          minRows={3}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setrevValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, body: e.target.value }))
          }
        />
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={onSubmit}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </FormControl>
    </Paper>
    </> 
  );
}

export default ReviewCreateForm;
```

This is the controller on the backend,

```
    module.exports.createReview = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { countryId } = req.params;
  const { title, body, rating, user } = req.body;

  const username = req.user.username

  const country = await Country.findById(countryId)
      
  const creatorId = req.user._id;
  const currentUser = await User.findById(creatorId)
  .populate('reviews')
  
  if (currentUser) {
    const alreadyReviewed = currentUser.reviews.find(
      (r) => r.countryId.toString() === req.params.countryId.toString()
    )

    if (alreadyReviewed) {
      res.status(400)
      return res.json({ message: 'You have already reviewed this country' })
      //throw new Error('Product already reviewed')
      
    }
  }
  try {

  const reviewdoc = new Review({
    title,
    rating: rating,
    body,
    creatorName: username,
    creatorId,
    countryId,
  });

  const review = await reviewdoc.save();

      
  country.reviews.push(review._id);

  currentUser.reviews.push(review._id);

  country.numReviews = country.reviews.length;

  let avgRating = country.overallRating;

  country.overallRating = parseFloat(avgRating + ((review.rating - avgRating) /
                               (country.reviews.length))).toFixed(2);

      await country.save();  
      await currentUser.save();
    
    return res.status(201).json({ message: "success" });

  } catch (error) {
    return console.log("error during createReview", error);
  }
};
```

Also feel free to give advice on stackoverflow question etiquette because I'm still new to asking questions here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `onSubmit` function needs to be called on the form element and not the button to prevent default form behaviour.

```
<FormControl fullWidth sx={{ rowGap: 2 }} size="medium" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
```

Then button should be of type submit

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
  Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried this but now the form doesn't submit at all